# Ejabberd custom IQ Handler: getting feature-not-implemented or service-unavailable

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I stripped `mod_last.erl` to test the creation of a IQHandler (pasted only the part that matters):

```
start(Host, Opts) ->
    IQDisc = gen_mod:get_opt(iqdisc, Opts, fun gen_iq_handler:check_type/1,
                             one_queue),
    gen_iq_handler:add_iq_handler(ejabberd_local, Host,
                  <<"join">>, ?MODULE, process_local_iq, IQDisc).

stop(Host) ->
    gen_iq_handler:remove_iq_handler(ejabberd_local, Host,
                     <<"join">>).

process_local_iq(_From, _To,
         #iq{type = Type, sub_el = SubEl} = IQ) ->
    case Type of
      set ->
      IQ#iq{type = error, sub_el = [SubEl, ?ERR_NOT_ALLOWED]};
      get ->
      Sec = 60,
      IQ#iq{type = result,
        sub_el =
            [#xmlel{name = <<"query">>,
                attrs =
                [{<<"xmlns">>, <<"join">>},
                 {<<"seconds">>,
                  iolist_to_binary(integer_to_list(Sec))}],
                children = []}]}
    end.
```

But when I send the request:

```
<iq type='get' id='123'>
    <query xmlns='join'/>
</iq>
```

I keep getting the **service-unavailable** error:

```
<iq from='alfred@localhost' to='alfred@localhost/Alfreds-MacBook-Pro' type='error' id='123'>
<query xmlns='join'/>
<error code='503' type='cancel'>
    <service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
</error>
</iq>
```

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548564/service-unavailable-response-from-server-while-sending-custom-iq) wasn't helpful, since I'm not adding `to`.

Note: the IQHandler that I want to create is to request joining game rooms.

Comment: can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734043/chat-app-for-android-using-a-xmpp-server-and-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-push-n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you send an IQ stanza without a `to` attribute, the server will "handle the stanza on behalf of the sending entity" ([RFC 6120, section 10.3.3](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#rules-noto-IQ)). In practice, that means that the server will treat the stanza as if the `to` attribute had been the bare JID of the user, in this case `alfred@localhost`.

When you call `gen_iq_handler:add_iq_handler` to register a new handler, you also specify the "scope", either `ejabberd_local` or `ejabberd_sm` ("SM" stands for "session manager").  If it's `ejabberd_local`, the handler will react to IQ stanzas addressed to the server itself, in this case `localhost`.  If it's `ejabberd_sm`, the handler will react to IQ stanzas addressed to the bare JID of a local user, e.g. `alfred@localhost`.

So that's why your IQ stanza ends up not being handled.  Either include `to="localhost"` when sending the request, or change `ejabberd_local` to `ejabberd_sm` when registering the handler.

Comment: That was it, when I tried with a `to` I was giving the full JID, so of course it wouldn't work because the resource can't handle the Iq. Also finally understood the difference between the local and sm handlers, thank you!

Comment: can you  please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734043/chat-app-for-android-using-a-xmpp-server-and-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-push-n